# Passing a placeholder for an optimizer results in an error "initial_value must have shape specified"

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder

Training a network, wanted to be able to pass the beta1 parameter as an argument and therefore made it a placeholder

`self.beta1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)`

a couple of lines later an error occurs on this line

`self.train_adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.eta, beta1=self.beta1, epsilon=1e-15).minimize(self.cost_m)`

Error:
`ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Placeholder_5:0", dtype=float32)`

Taking `beta1=self.beta1` out results in the error disappearing so the error must have to do with that.

I have no clue why this is happening as `placeholders` do not need to have a shape specified. I have tried using `self.beta1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None)`, that also doesn't work, same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Over a year later I encounter the same problem and then remember I've asked about it before. What a bizarre design decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give a shape `[]` to your placeholder, as it is a constant:

```
self.beta1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
```

Comment: As a remark, adding `shape=None` has no effect because python already assumes `shape` to be `None` by default when the argument is not specified.

Comment: Of course. But It shouldn't be complaining in the first place as `placeholders` don't need to be declared with a shape. I tried that just to do something.